# QE-DEF-0368 Unable to Decrypt User Name and Password when selecting datasource in IBM Cognos connection

Tags: sql, cognos

We have an IBM Cognos 10.2.2. We recently create a new datawarehouse in MS SQL 17. From IBM Framework Manager, we created a connection to MS SQL using OLEDB and tested the connectivity successfully.

When use try to create a new project through Cognos connection they get the above error when they selected the datasource that was created from the framework Manager.

Any idea what is wrong?  I looked that IBM technote but it seems to suggest that you can't even create the connection in the first place.

Comment: I am guessing this is for users that have a the role/group of author.
Sounds like it might be an authority issue.  Can you share the properties for the package published by framework manager? In particular permissions for read/write traverse,etc
and compare that to the role of an author

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused by the Encryption Keys being out of synchronization between the Framework Manager install and the IBM Cognos Server.   Try re-doing your FM keys and re-creating a new connection to see what happens.

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/resolving-qe-def-0368-unable-decrypt-user-name-and-password